# Problem with company-anaconda and company-yasnippet

Tags: company-mode, yasnippet

I have tried several setups and I just can't seem to be able to get anaconda and yasnippet working at the same time (dabbrev would be nice as well). First I tried reorganizing the order, it was a suggestion somewhere. If one puts anaconda higher(first) than yasnippet, then anaconda will show in the dropdown and yasnippet won't be listed in the dropdown (`yas-expand` works though).

This is my current order:

```el
(company-anaconda company-bbdb company-nxml company-css company-eclim
  company-semantic company-clang company-xcode company-cmake company-capf
  company-files (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords
                 company-web-html company-yasnippet) company-oddmuse)
```

If I place `company-anaconda` below(after) company-oddmuse, then yasnippet works, but anaconda does not.

Also tried something like this, to have it specifically working under python-mode, also does not work:

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
              (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends) '(company-anaconda :with company-yasnippet))
                      (company-mode t)))
```

Or

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
              (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends) '(company-anaconda company-yasnippet))
                      (company-mode t)))
```

In the above cases changing the order also does not make a difference. Anyone having problems with this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok It seems that I have found an answer myself. Here it is for anybody wanting it as well:

`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                 '((company-anaconda company-dabbrev-code company-yasnippet)))))`